# PyDev adding random imports

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm using PyDev with LiClipse and every once in a while I take a gander up to the top of a file of mine to find something like this:

```
from compiler.ast import Name
from twisted.words.test.test_basesupport import self
from macpath import curdir
```

That is, totally random imports that are sort of related to names I am typing but are most definitely the wrong things to try to import.

Why is this happening and how do I make it stop?

Comment: Probably because it actually needs it?

Comment: @aIKid: erm, no. no it does not. these are superfluous imports that it mistakenly created from temporarily undefined variables (e.g. it auto-completed the non-existent global variable `Name` instead of the existent local variable `name` and then added an import for it from some random-ass module.)

Comment: What's your python version and code completion settings? My guess it has something to do with auto import althrough I can't reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: @alko: py 2.7 , I have: 0 autocompletion delay, 1 min chars for deep analysis for parameters in 'from' imports, request completion on `.`, `(`, and all letter chars and `_`.

Comment: I can get those `from macpath import curdir` when pressing ctrl-shift-o, but only with some prompt from pydev (i.e. choice from `macpath`, `ntpath` etc.). There is also second, ctx-intensive part of code completion settings.

Comment: @alko: oh yes i see this setting now for auto import, i'll turn it off and see if that helps

Comment: I am seeing the same error - it has caused me a few debugging headaches as it kept randomly auto adding old classes that would break things.

Comment: The solution is to use PyCharm instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out why this was happening to me.

In the PyDev code auto complete if I started typing a variable name a couple of matches would come up with a Class name next to them.

If you click on one of the autocomplete options with a different class name to the one you are working in PyDev automatically imports the file into the file / class you are working on.